# Manage Chrome add-ons using C#

Tags: c#, google-chrome

How to enable and disable chrome add-ons using C#. What should be the approach for this requirement? I searched on internet but didn't get any luck on this so far. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to do this by manipulating Chrome user data directory.

Please note that with the new profiles there can be more than one directory (one for
each profile), you can find a list of the profiles and their usernames in the "Local State" file that you will find in the user data directory.

In the profile directory you'll find a "Preferences" file, this file contains what extensions are installed and whether their enabled. The state key of each extension object determines whether its enabled, its 0 if its disabled and 1 if it isnt. Both the "Local State" and "Preferences" files are in JSON format.

Following are some default locations..

**Windows XP**

- Google Chrome: C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local
  Settings\Application Data\Google\Chrome\User Data\Default
- Chromium: C:\Documents and Settings\%USERNAME%\Local
  Settings\Application Data\Chromium\User Data\Default

**Windows 8 or 7 or Vista**

- Google Chrome: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User
  Data\Default
- Chromium: C:\Users\%USERNAME%\AppData\Local\Chromium\User
  Data\Default

**Mac OS X**

- Google Chrome: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default
- Chromium: ~/Library/Application Support/Chromium/Default

**Linux**

- Google Chrome: ~/.config/google-chrome/Default
- Chromium: ~/.config/chromium/Default

**Chrome OS**

- /home/chronos/

Comment: but how we can achieve this in .NET.

Comment: There are various classes available to manipulate directories and files. More info: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_file_io.htm